# UFT/QTP General Run time error with .GetRoProperty

Tags: runtime-error, qtp, hp-uft

Hello I am getting a general run time error. This am working with preloaded drop downs and I have another one function before this that works just fine. but when it tries to run this I get the error.

I have tried with different properties like innertext, html id, ect.. but this get the same error.

```vbs
Sub WebList(DropDown)

    Set myPage=Browser("title:=.*").Page("title:=.*")    
    Set myWebList=Description.Create()
    myWebList("micClass").value="WebList"
    Set AllWebList=myPage.ChildObjects(myWebList)
    totalWebList=AllWebList.count()

    For i = 0 To totalWebList
       If AllWebList(i).GetRoProperty("name") = DropDown  Then
           AllWebList(i).select ("GO") 
           wait(3)
           Exit for    
       End If       
   Next

   Set myPage = nothing
   Set myWebList2 = Nothing
   Set AllWebList2 = nothing        
End Sub
```

I want the dropdown to be selected. Thanks for any help/suggestion. Also if I can improve on any lines to make it for dynamic and experienced coder, please do suggest them.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your `For` loop, if there are no lists with the specified name you will access one more than actually exist. This is due to the fact that `To` in vbscript is inclusive and the index starts at `0`. If the list is found the code works for me.

The `For` loop should be:

```
For i = 0 to totatlWebList - 1
```